# Resolve SSIS Package with Kingswaysoft error: Connection type "DynamicsCRM" is not recognized as a valid connection manager type

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I am using [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) to create an [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis) package targeted at [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012).  I am using [KingswaySoft](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/help-manual/crm) to connect to [dynamics-crm](/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm) to read & update some data. My package runs correctly when I run it from Visual Studio.  However, when I deploy the package to my server, the package no longer runs successfully.  I am receiving multiple errors with the first error being:

> The connection type "DynamicsCRM" specified for connection manager "Dynamics CRM Connection Manager" is not recognized a valid connection manager type.

Why am I receiving this error and why is it only showing up when the package has been deployed?

I have tried restarting the Integration Services on the server.

I checked the license on the server and I noticed that although I have the Ultimate Edition of KingswaySoft, one of the License Manager's doesn't have a license and won't accept my license key.  Perhaps it's a licensing issue?

[image: License]

Comment: did you buy the license for KingswaySoft?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes - I also confirmed that the license is active on the server

Comment: then contact KingswaySoft support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that you do not have our software installed on your integration server.

Edit:
Re-installation solved the issue (per comments)

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I have the software installed and I have an Ultimate Edition License.

Comment: It would happen if it is an incomplete installation such as you run our software installation before you add a  new SSIS runtime. You may consider running the manual install package that we provided on our download page to see if it helps. Please reach out to us directly through our email account so that we can have a look of the issue remotely if this is still an issue.

Comment: I have sent an email to your support email.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us. After we have re-installed the software, the above issue got resolved. We would like to thank you for choosing KingswaySoft, we appreciate your continued support.